# UnityContainerExtensions.LoadConfiguration() Error

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Below error I am getting while container.LoadConfiguration("")

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Unity.Configuration.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

---

Few details:
I am using .NET 4.5.2
Unity 5.2.1

Below is the code

```
 IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        UnityConfigurationSection section = new UnityConfigurationSection();
        container.LoadConfiguration("DataAccessProvider");  //Here it is throwing error

        section.Configure(container);

        var dataAccessProvider = container.Resolve<IDataProvider>("SQLDataAccessProvider");
        return dataAccessProvider;
```

App.config as below
[image]

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have the following configuration working without any issues - .NET 4.5.2 Unity 5.2.1

```
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
unityContainer.LoadConfiguration("DataAccessProvider");
var dataAccessProvider = unityContainer.Resolve<IDataProvider>("SQLDataAccessProvider");
return dataAccessProvider;
```

Config:
[image]

Hope that helps.